# Passing an object by reference to function doesnt change this object

Tags: c++, function, pointers, reference

so basically, I'm trying to pass an object to my function `Attack()`:

```
void Character::Attack(Character &another, short int range)
{
    if (EnemyInRange(range) && another.health > 0)
    {
        if (allowed_to_attack)
        {
            attacked = true;

            cout << name << " attacked " << another.name << " taking " << attack << " damage" << endl;


            if (another.defensive > 0) // less important things down there
            {
                another.defensive--;

                if (attack > another.defensive)
                {
                    another.health -= (attack - another.defensive);
                }
            }
            else if (another.defensive == 0)
            {
                another.health -= attack;
            }


            if (another.defensive <= 0)
                another.defensive = 0;

            if (another.health <= 0)
            {
                another.health = 0;
                another.draw = false;
                another.~Character();
            }

        }

        else
        {
            attacked = false;
            cout << "Blocked" << endl;
        }

    }
    else
        cout << name << " wanted to attack " << another.name << " ,but he's out of the range" << endl;
```

As you see, I'm using reference to pass an object. BUT, when I call this function:

```
void onClick(Vector2f mouse_position, Character current, Character *& target, Position &positionx)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            if ((mouse_position.x >= 245 + i * 164 && mouse_position.x <= 370 + i * 164) &&
                (mouse_position.y >= 56 + j * 201 && mouse_position.y <= 221 + j * 201))
            { // there's a 2d map with cards on those positions
                target = &positionx.positioning[i][j];
                current.Attack(*target);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

> positioning is an array filled with characters

It's behaving like I passed a copy of an object target (it writes out name, but it doesn't change its health)

in main() it looks like this:

```
Character *current = new Character();
Character *target = NULL;
```

---

```
if ((event.type == Event::MouseButtonPressed) && (event.mouseButton.button == Mouse::Left))//SFML lib
{
    Vector2i pos = Mouse::getPosition(window);
    Vector2f position = (Vector2f)pos;
    onClick(position, *current, target, positionx);
} // target is selected after clicking on it
```

Comment: Why do you manually call the destructor `another.~Character();` and what does this destructor do? This may cause strange behavior and there is almost no reason to manually call a destructor.

Comment: I wanted to make sure, that if character's health drops to 0, it will get destroyed

Answer (score 1):

In the function `onClick`, the variable `current` is passed by value not reference. I assume that is supposed to be passed by reference:

```
void onClick(Vector2f mouse_position, Character &current, Character *target, Position &positionx)
```

Notice the argument `current` has been updated to a reference.

Edit:

Looking at the body of the `Attack` function, if the line printing out the name is met, are you sure the if-conditional statements `if(another.defensive > 0)` and `if(attack > another.defensive)` are met?

Comment: Isn't the question about "target"? As far as I see "current" modifies "target", or at least should modify it.

Comment: SKCoder is right. I wanted to make  " *target " modified, and "current" is object that runs "Attack()" method. I changed current to reference, but its still not working

Comment: @Azam Every thing was working fine when i was using Attack outside onClick function.

Answer (score 0):

Do you think that `Position &positionx` might be a problem here? The most important part of `onClick()` function is `target = &positionx.positioning[i][j]`. But its passed by reference, so it shouldnt make a problem.